# How to add a box-shadow with inset to a div containing a youtube iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I need to add a inner shadow using CSS `box-shadow: inset` to a div which contains an iframe from YouTube.
I can change the structure for the dom inside node with id `widget` but not outside.

- Is it possible?
- Could you provide me an example?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#widget {
  position: absolute;
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: inset 50px 50px 25px #888888;
  border: 50px solid blue;
}

#iframe {}
```

```html
<div id="widget">
  <iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NWHfY_lvKIQ?rel=0&amp;controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a pseudo element using `:after` for the container and put it on top of the video, add the shadow and add `pointer-events: none;` to make it inexistent for the mouse interacting with the video.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#widget {
    position: absolute;
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    border: 50px solid blue;
}

#widget:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  box-shadow: inset 50px 50px 25px #888888;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget">
        <iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NWHfY_lvKIQ?rel=0&amp;controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

EDIT: I know old versions of internet explorer have a little bit of problems with elements over a youtube video, to fix it add the `?wmode=transparent` GET parameter to the youtube iframe url.

Comment: Only problem I have on chrome, is that the rounded corners for a moment are disappearing when the video is being loaded. Do you have a solution for this glitch? Thanks

Comment: You can fix it by adding border-radius: 50px; to the pseudo element. It's 50px because the outer radius is 100px and the border-width is 50px, so 100-50=50px; (I updated the demo above)